# reactjs assigning ref to element inside child component return null

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I am trying to target ref on an element inside my child component, but still always return null, in the pic I put some condition on the component, I have tried to remove the loading logic and still return null on the ref

Comment: Have you tried logging it inside of a useEffect? Since you are logging at the time where the return has not been reached so the div that you want to reference has not been rendered and the ref has not been assigned yet so it's undefined.

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly.